# excel forms appear with blank color

Tags: forms

I have windows 10 and use excel 16. Even if in project mode a form is light blue when I execute the macro all forms I made (both new ones and those made in excel 2007) are visualized with the title not colored, blank: does somebody know why?

../users/8032576/francesco
excel forms appear with blank color

To make relevant  my precedent question asked May 18  maybe I can add some information to clarify the problem. The form in project time looks like the image at the right while at execution time it looks like the one at left 
[enter image description here][1] project
[enter image description here][2] execution

My computer graphic chipset has the following features:
Chipset grafico - AMD Radeon(TM) R7 M440, Tipo di bus - PCI Express 3.0, Versione BIOS - 015.049.000.012
Capacità della memoria - 4096 MB, Tipo di memoria - DDR3, Clock memoria - 900 MHz, Clock principale - 1021 MHz, Larghezza di banda totale della memoria - 14 GByte/s

Maybe my request is more complete.

Francesco

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to my own question thanks to Norman David Jone who suggested me: https://support.microsoft.com/it-it/help/17144/windows-10-change-desktop-background
However I would thank you for your hospitality.
Francesco